# Rickshaw physics

Tags: design, tricycle

[image]

I wanted to know the physics behind the working of such a model. Specifically, the relationship between the force applied by the Rider and the weight of the passengers.

Comment: Is this a practical cycling problem that you face in the real world?  Or is this your physics homework?

Comment: What is your question?  The passengers are basically just dead weight.  The canopy contributes far more wind resistance than the passengers.  On level ground wind resistance determines speed (if the tires are decent).  Going up a hill it's weight that is the biggie.  Force applied is the good old F=MA, with the acceleration of gravity taken into account on a slope.

Comment: Edited to change tags as it had nothing to do with "chain" or "commuting."

Answer (score 4):

To accelerate, the peddler is accelerating the weight of three people plus the bicycle.  Once moving, the [rolling resistance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolling_resistance) generally scales with the weight of the total vehicle.  the rear wheels and tires have to be sized to carry the weight.  The Wikpedia article gives 0.0055 as a typical rolling resistance coefficient for typical BMX tires, which is more like what I would expect than road race tires for a vehicle like this.  Vehicles like this have rather low gearing so the pedal force is within the strength of the rider.  For a given vehicle, the pedal force will be proportional to the total weight carried.  The speeds are low enough that air resistance is not a huge issue, though the sun cover increases it.

Comment: This might be the first correct use of "peddler" in this site's history.

Comment: Does that make the passengers the Peddlee's? :P